# Sitecore PAAS Redis Exception

Tags: azure, paas, redis

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 deployed in PAAS and CD app service is showing  below error  and logs are full of this kind of exceptions:

> ERROR ProcessExpiredItems => System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing EVAL, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 3933, qu: 3933, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000),
>
> WORKER: 
>   (Busy=3,Free=32764,Min=50,Max=32767), clientName: RD0004FFDF4447at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)at
>
> StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)at 
>   StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags)at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<Eval>b__0()at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryForScriptNotFound(Func`1 redisOperation)at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation)at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs)at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisExpirationIndexWrapper.GetSessionFromExpirationIndex(DateTime signalTime, DateTime processExpirationTime)at Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.d__27.MoveNext()at
>
> Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider.OnProcessExpiredItems(DateTime signalTime)2019-03-28T13:43:08

What I want to understand is that meaning of queue: being very high i.e 3933 more than max number what does this means?

Comment: What i want to understand is that meaning of queue: being very high i.e 3933 more than max number what does this means

Comment: Might be worth updating the question to reflect that.  Although not a Sitecore specific question the queue and qu values indicate there are troubles submitting to redis from the client.  Details and troubleshooting ideas can be found here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same kind of issues.
We were able to resolve them by tweaking the **polling interval** of the private session state provider and increasing the **timeoutBetweenLockAttempts** of the shared session state manager.

Private Session State:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager" customProvider="redis">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="private" connectionString="redis.sessions" pollingInterval="230" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Shared session state manager:

```
  <sharedSessionState defaultProvider="redis" patch:source="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="InProc" type="System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore" />
      <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" connectionString="redis.sessions" applicationName="shared" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" pollingInterval="30" />
    </providers>
    <manager type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.SharedSessionState.SharedSessionStateManager, Sitecore.Analytics">
      <param ref="tracking/sharedSessionState/config" desc="configuration" />
    </manager>
    <config type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.SharedSessionState.SharedSessionStateConfig, Sitecore.Analytics">
      <param desc="maxLockAge">5000</param>
      <param desc="timeoutBetweenLockAttempts">10200</param>
    </config>
  </sharedSessionState>
```

Comment: The pollingInterval value needs to be set between 2 to 60, it will not accept more than that. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/858026

Answer (score -1):

- `inst` - the number of commands that have been issued in the last time slice,
- `mgr` - operation that socked manager is performing,
- `queue` - it's a number of in-progress operations,
- `qu` - the number of in-progress operations that are in an unsent queue,
- `qs` - the number of in-progress operations that have been sent to the server but a response is not yet available,
- `qc` - the number of in-progress operations that have seen replies but have not yet been marked as complete due to waiting on the completion loop,
- `wr` - the number of active writer bytes/activewriters
- `in` - number of active readers/bytes available to be read